# Select Top X records starting at record Y

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am using MS Access VBA to make a few queries. I have a list of about 4000 items and I need query 1 to be the top 739 items and query 2 to be the top 428 items starting at record 740 and I need query 3 to be the rest starting at record 1168.

is there any way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: also there are no unique identifiers.

Comment: Yes, it can be done. Did you tried to do it? If so, please share your effort and you will find people here eager to help you. But please don't post question in this forums looking for responses of your question without you make an effort first.

Comment: My apologies, I have had a crazy few days. I have attempted the below suggestion and still need to make a few adjustments before I have a solid response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a query that will assign an ID to each record using one of the methods listed in my project [VBA.RowNumbers](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.RowNumbers).

The function *RowNumber* may fit you.

You will have to use a *compound key* (`say, Field1 & "|" & Field2 & "|" & Field9`) to obtain something unique, or you can't do this.

Then run these queries:

```sql
Select * From YourQuery
Where ID Between 1 And 739

Select * From YourQuery
Where ID Between 740 And 1167

Select * From YourQuery
Where ID >= 1168
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, with what you posted I was able to create a field with sequential numbers however i might have done something wrong. they are not in sequential order. i have one field that needs to be highest to lowest and if i make the RowID field ascending order then my main field will be out of wack.

Comment: If the "main" field is not unique, there is no way to create a specific order of records having identical values for the field. That's why a compound key is needed for such cases.

Comment: My main field is based on a LocationID which is never duplicated. im really sorry that i can't give you any specific data.

Comment: You wrote: _also there are no unique identifiers._ But if there is one, sort on this and forget the compound key.

Comment: I didn't realize that until later, I apologize. I am so sorry for the confusion. i wasn't paying attention to what fields i had added to it.
This worked great thank you so much for your help

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!